# Autocompleting \cite{} with emacs + auctex gives "cite: no such database entry"

Tags: emacs, auctex

I am running Emacs 23.1.1 and AucTeX 11.85 in an Ubuntu 8.10 machine. After opening a tex file, the first time I try to use the autocompletion of the \cite{} command, I get

"cite: info not available, use `C-c &' to get it."

in the minibuffer. After doing the 'C-c &', I get

"byte-code: No BibTeX entry with citation key".

Subsequent calls to \cite gives me the message

"cite: no such database entry" .

I have a \bibliography{library} in my tex file, and the \cite{} entries that I did manually work as expected.

I have the following in my .emacs

```
(require 'reftex)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode) ;turn on pdf-mode.  AUCTeX
                                          ;will call pdflatex to
                                          ;compile instead of latex.
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode) ;turn on math-mode by
                                             ;default
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'reftex-mode) ;turn on REFTeX mode by
                                         ;default
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode) ;turn on flyspell mode by
                                           ;default

(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-save-query nil)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

I also tried the suggestions in [Suggestion for \cite in Emacs with AUCTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699017/suggestion-for-cite-in-emacs-with-auctex), but it didn't work either.

Alejandro.

Comment: Did you run bibtex at least once before trying to autocomplete? Did you try C-c [

Comment: I run bibtex before. Same behavior. However, C-c [ does the trick! Thanks.

Comment: Find a way to close your question, then, to make it be answered. Maybe write an answer and tick it?

Comment: I think that the \cite autocompletion should work (just by typing \cite{). I am waiting for an answer :).

Comment: It seems I am not going to get a better answer. I just add my answer. I need to wait 14 hours to tick it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C-c [ works. 
(I am not sure if after typing \cite{ I should get the completion, but I am happy with the other solution.)

Answer (score 2):

I followed the previously mentioned steps and found that C-c [ works well. I was also able to view the available citations by using the following commands:

1.) C-c <enter> 
2.) type: \cite <enter> 
3.) type: searchTerm <enter>

Where searchTerm is a regular expression for an item in your .bib file. As previously mentioned, make sure you run bibtex and latex before attempting the \cite auto-complete.